Having Trouble Implementing Partition-key-based Multi-Tenancy and Search with Milvus
I am attempting to implement Partition-key-based multi-tenancy, but I was not able to find any code implementation tutorial for me to follow along.
Here is the code I have so far. However, I am having trouble figuring out if this is the correct way to execute and what would be the proper next step for searching with Milvus?
schema = MilvusClient.create_schema(auto_id=True, enable_dynamic_field=True, primary_field="id")

schema.add_field(field_name="id", datatype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True)
schema.add_field(field_name="source", datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=50000)
schema.add_field(field_name="embeddings", datatype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=self.truncate_dim)
schema.add_field(field_name="tenant", datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, is_partition_key=True) # i set the is_partition_key to True

index_params = MilvusClient.prepare_index_params()

index_params.add_index(field_name="id", index_type="STL_SORT")
index_params.add_index(
    field_name="embeddings",
    index_type="IVF_FLAT",
    metric_type="L2",
    params={"nlist": 1024},
)

self.milvusClient.create_collection(
    collection_name=self.collection_name,
    schema=schema,
    index_params=index_params,
    partition_key_field="tenant" # added a partition_key_field inside here
)


Here is a good example I found that could be helpful for you:
from pymilvus import (
    DataType,

    MilvusClient,
)

milvusClient = MilvusClient("http://localhost:19530")

dim = 128
collection_name = "XXX"
schema = MilvusClient.create_schema(auto_id=True, enable_dynamic_field=True, primary_field="id")

schema.add_field(field_name="id", datatype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True)
schema.add_field(field_name="source", datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=50000)
schema.add_field(field_name="embeddings", datatype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=dim)
schema.add_field(field_name="tenant", datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=50000, is_partition_key=True) # i set the is_partition_key to True

index_params = MilvusClient.prepare_index_params()

index_params.add_index(field_name="id", index_type="STL_SORT")
index_params.add_index(
    field_name="embeddings",
    index_type="IVF_FLAT",
    metric_type="L2",
    params={"nlist": 1024},
)

milvusClient.create_collection(
    collection_name=collection_name,
    schema=schema,
    index_params=index_params,
)

entities = [
    {"source": "blah blah vlah", "embeddings": [0.5 for _ in range(dim)], "tenant": "aaa"},
    {"source": "hello world", "embeddings": [1.5 for _ in range(dim)], "tenant": "bbb"},
    {"source": "good day", "embeddings": [2.5 for _ in range(dim)], "tenant": "ccc"},
]
insert_result = milvusClient.insert(collection_name=collection_name, data=entities)
print(insert_result)

search_params={"metric_type": "L2", "params": {"nprobe": 10}}
search_vectors = [[0.5 for _ in range(dim)]]
result = milvusClient.search(
    collection_name=collection_name,
    data=search_vectors,
    filter="tenant==\"bbb\"",
    search_params=search_params,
    anns_field="embeddings",
    limit=10,
    output_fields=["source", "tenant"],
    consistency_level="Strong", # comment out this line, search result could be empty
)
print(result)

milvusClient.drop_collection(collection_name=collection_name)

